# Asymptotically Optimal Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

I am confused how to check if an algorithm I made is asymptotically optimal.

At the very least, the running time is constant at O(4). This is because you will need to check at least 4 names.

At the very most, the running time is linear at O(n). 
This is from n + n + n/2 + n/2 + n/4 + n/4 + .... = 2n * (1 + 1/2 +...) < 2n. As we ignore constants its just O(n).

I checked on Wiki and it said that the algorithm should perform at worst a constant factor of the best algorithm. But if you invented an algorithm then how do I figure this out?

Comment: Some details are missing here (such as the problem itself you're trying to solve), but they don't seem important. Can you rephrase your question to include only the salient information, yet be completely comprehensible?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We usually only care about the *worst-case complexity* of algorithms. An $O(n)$ algorithm is usually asymptotically optimal (assuming $n$ is the input size), since most functions require you to read the entire input in some cases.

Another example in which you can prove asymptotic optimality is comparison-based sorting algorithms. A comparison-based sorting algorithm is a sorting algorithm whose only access to the data is a comparison oracle, which compares to data items. Any such algorithm must make $\Omega(n\log n)$ oracle queries in the worst case. Therefore a comparison-based sorting algorithm running in time $O(n\log n)$ is asymptotically optimal.

In most cases, however, we cannot prove that a given algorithm running in superlinear time is optimal, since we don't know how to prove running time lower bounds on general computation models. However, in some cases we can prove such lower bounds conditionally, that is, assuming some widely believed hypothesis. This is known as *fine-grained complexity theory*, and it indicates (conditionally) that the best algorithms for many problems are indeed asymptotically optimal.

Comment: But how would I know if my algorithm is 'best' if it is an undefined problem e.g. not a sort. It could be a search algorithm for example in a 3-D space. If you found the value you wanted in the first pass then that would be the 'best' solution no?

Comment: You wouldn't know in general, unless your algorithm happens to run in linear time, and the problem is such that the output potentially depends on the entire input.

Comment: So if I know for sure my algorithm runs in O(n) I can assume it is asymptotic optimal? How would I argue this is true?

Comment: You would need a matching $\Omega(n)$ lower bound, but these are often not hard to prove.

Comment: Can you kindly give me an example or point me to an example please?

Comment: Checking whether an input string is the all-0 string takes time $\Omega(n)$, where $n$ is the length of the string, since if your algorithm doesn't examine all positions, you might miss a 1. This is not a formal proof, but can be turned into a formal proof. In the same way, BFS and DFS are optimal for many tasks such as connectivity, though the proof is a bit more delicate and there are some issues of encoding.

Comment: In my algortihm, the first step is to open n boxes. Then n boxes. Then n/2 boxes. And so on. This gives an upper bound running time of O(2n). As in the first iteration you need to open at least n boxes I'm guessing a lower bound is O(n). Where I am confused is how to argue, using this, that my algorithm is or isn't asymptotically optimal. The definition is that the worst case needs to be a constant times the best case. Is the best case O(n) or simply 1?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to ask that as a new question. Don't forget to also state your problem, we can't read your mind.

Comment: No problem I will do this now. :)

Comment: Hi I posted it here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71435/how-to-prove-algorithm-correctness-and-test-asymptotical-optimality